# Missing UserPermissions in Profiles and Missing workflow

Tags: workflow, mavensmate, git, sublime

I'm missing a UserPermission for "Files Connect Cloud" after a Clean in Sublime Text 3 when using Mavensmate. I'm trying to Edit the project to add the missing metadata but I cannot find what metadata is missing, since other UserPermissions in my profiles are working as intended but not the "Files Connect Cloud". Where is this located in the metadata?

I'm also unable to find my workflow for the CaseComment object, I have added the Workflow metadata folder and my other workflows are present here, but the one for CaseComment. I cannot find CaseComment as an object neither. Anyone know where this is located?

Comment: I was unable to find the CaseComment object in mavensmate, I submitted an Issue in their GitHub page but noanswer yet. My solution right now was to add these changes directly in the Prod environment, not optimal but working for now. I hope that they fix this soon, or if anyone solves this in some way please let me know.